# For a graph G with greater than or equal to 3 vertices, prove that G is Hamitonian if there is a Hamiltonian path between every pair of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

As the title of the question states, a proof for this proposition will be highly appreciated. The proof can either be inductive or, explained in plain English.

Comment: Side note: a cycle graph with four vertices disproves the converse statement "In a Hamiltonian graph, there is a Hamiltonian path between any two vertices".

Comment: Is my answer wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Consider two adjacent verices $A$ and $B$ and let $p$ be the path connecting them by hypothesis. Since it must begin in $A$ and end in $B$, $p$ does not contain the edge $e$ connecting $A$ and $B$. Hence, it is enough to consider $p\cup\{e\}$.